# Slider default value not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 JQueryUI Range Slider but they return the default value but they contain another value here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kem5tcbL/).

I think the `value: 20,` in the all of the `.slider()` doesn't really works.

But I want to have 20 as a default contained value.

Thanks :D

Comment: Please explain your problem

Comment: @GovindSamrow My problem is : return the default value but they contain another value

Comment: What another value ? As I seen your slider there is a logic which  calculate the value of price field. So default value is 20.

Comment: @GovindSamrow I updated it look : https://jsfiddle.net/kem5tcbL/1/

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: @GovindSamrow when you move the first slider you have a number like 400, but month = 1 by default and 21 ( if you move ) for slots. And month*slots= 21 normaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in your logic ,Try Update fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/kem5tcbL/2/)

```
var price = slots * month;
```